# CreateJS Angular 4

Tags: angular

How exactly do you install and use createjs in Angular 4.

I have installed the @types and the package (although the package doesn't look like it has installed correctly as it has a version number of 0.0.1).

Importing createjs from createjs gets me this message:

```
Failed to compile.

C:/Users/Me/Documents/repos/test-createjs-app-a4/src/app/app.component.ts (2,26): File 'C:/Users/Me/Documents/repos/test-createjs-app-a4/node_modules/@types/createjs/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so just figured it out.

You need to install createjs-module like this (not just createjs):

```
npm install createjs-module --save
```

And import createjs like this:

```
import * as createjs from 'createjs-module';
```

Then the usual createjs stuff is possible:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The one remaining step I need is how to import and implement an animation exported from Adobe Animate (it exports to CreateJS).